# Python BeautifulSoup append contents without outermost tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I will ask my question with an example that does "almost what I want":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

p = BeautifulSoup(features='lxml').new_tag('p')
p.append('This is my paragraph. I can add a ')
a = BeautifulSoup(features='lxml').new_tag('a', href='www.google.com')
a.string = 'link to Google'
p.append(a)
p.append(' and finish my paragraph.')

div = BeautifulSoup(features='lxml').new_tag('div')
div.append("I want to append the paragraph content into this div, but only its content without the <p> and </p>, and don't want to escape anything in the contents, i.e. I want to keep the a tag. ")
div.append(p)

print(div.prettify())
```

As a result, `print(div)` shows

```
<div>
 I want to append the paragraph content into this div, but only its content without the &lt;p&gt; and &lt;/p&gt;, and don't want to escape anything in the contents, i.e. I want to keep the a tag.
 <p>
  This is my paragraph. I can add a
  <a href="www.google.com">
   link to Google
  </a>
  and finish my paragraph.
 </p>
</div>
```

As the text in the example itself says, I want to append the inner HTML of `p` without the `<p>` and `</p>` tags, but keeping all other tags (in this case the `a` tag). So for this example this is the result I want to get:

```
<div>
 I want to append the paragraph content into this div, but only its content without the &lt;p&gt; and &lt;/p&gt;, and don't want to escape anything in the contents, i.e. I want to keep the a tag. This is my paragraph. I can add a
  <a href="www.google.com">
   link to Google
  </a>
  and finish my paragraph.
</div>
```

How can this be done? I have tried a number of options like `div.append(p.unwrap())` or `div.append(p.text)` and some others without luck. `div.append(str(p)[3:-4])` does not work because it escapes all the `<` and `>` from the inner elements, in this case `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) like this to get the desired result.

```
import bs4 as bs

s = '''
<div>
 I want to append the paragraph content into this div, but only its content without the &lt;p&gt; and &lt;/p&gt;, and don't want to escape anything in the contents, i.e. I want to keep the a tag.
 <p>
  This is my paragraph. I can add a
  <a href="www.google.com">
   link to Google
  </a>
  and finish my paragraph.
 </p>
</div>
'''
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

div_tag = soup.find('div')
div_tag.p.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

```
Output

<div>
 I want to append the paragraph content into this div, but only its content without the &lt;p&gt; and &lt;/p&gt;, and don't want to escape anything in the contents, i.e. I want to keep the a tag.
 
  This is my paragraph. I can add a
  <a href="www.google.com">
   link to Google
  </a>
  and finish my paragraph.
 
</div>
```